# Filtering file according to the highest value in a column of each line

Tags: awk

I have the following file:

```
gene.100079.0.5.p3  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   84.9
gene.100079.0.3.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   84.9
gene.100079.0.0.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   86.7
gene.100080.0.3.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   99.9
gene.100080.0.0.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   99.9
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t1   transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   74.9
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t2   transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   76.7
```

The above file has some IDs which are similar

```
gene.100079.0.5.p3
gene.100079.0.3.p1
gene.100079.0.0.p1
```

By remaining only `gene.100079` the IDs become identically. I would like to filter the above file in the following way:

- `chr11_pilon3.g3568.t1 = 74.9`. IDs starting with `chr` get excluded from the comparison and they end up straight in the output.
- `gene.100079.0.0.p1 = 86.7` && `gene.100079.0.5.p3 = 84.9` == `gene.100079.0.3.p1 = 84.9`. `gene.100079.0.0.p1` has the highest value and therefore it should be in the output.
- `gene.100080.0.3.p1 = 99.9` == `gene.100080.0.0.p1 = 99.9`. Both IDs have the same value and therefore both should be in the output.

However, this awk script from @RavinderSingh13 and @anubhava returns the wrong results.

```
awk '{
   if (/^gene\./) {
      split($1, a, /\./)
      k = a[1] "." a[2]
    }
    else
       k = $1
}
!(k in max) || $13 >= max[k] {
   if(!(k in max))
      ord[++n] = k
   else if (max[k] == $13) {
      print
      next
   }
   max[k] = $13
   rec[k] = $0
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      print rec[ord[i]]
}' file
```

Wrong output with the above script:

```
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t1   transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   74.9
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t2   transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   76.7
gene.100079.0.0.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   86.7
gene.100079.0.3.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   84.9
gene.100080.0.0.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   99.9
gene.100080.0.3.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   99.9
```

As output I would like to get:

```
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t1   transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   74.9
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t2   transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   76.7
gene.100079.0.0.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   86.7
gene.100080.0.3.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   99.9
gene.100080.0.0.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   99.9
```

I also tried to fix as show below but it didn't work:

```
awk '{
   if (/^gene\./) {
      split($1, a, /\./)
      k = a[1] "." a[2]
    }
    else
       k = $1
}
!(k in max) || $13 > max[k] {
   max[k]=$13; 
   line[k]=$0
}
END {
   for(i in line) 
      print line[i]
}'
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Please show your own effort.

Comment: I am sorry,, I did a mistake in the rules because  IDs starting with `chr` get excluded from the comparison and they end up straight in the output. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work correctly, assuming that the data is ordered so that all the lines with the same first two name components are grouped together in the data file.  The order of those lines within the group doesn't matter.

As revised, the question now wants lines starting `chr` transferred to the output without any filtering.  That is easily achieved — the rule matching `/^chr/` provides that functionality.

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '
    function dump_memo()
    {
        if (memo_num > 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < memo_num; i++)
                print memo_line[i]
        }
    }
    /^chr/ { print; next }         # Do not process lines starting chr specially
    {
        split($1, a, ".")
        key = a[1] "." a[2]
        val = $NF
        # print "# " key " = " val " (memo_key = " memo_key ", memo_val = " memo_val ")"
        if (memo_key == key)
        {
            if (memo_val == val)
            {
                memo_line[memo_num++] = $0
            }
            else if (memo_val < val)
            {
                memo_val = val
                memo_num = 0
                memo_line[memo_num++] = $0
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dump_memo()
            memo_num = 0
            memo_line[memo_num++] = $0
            memo_key = key
            memo_val = val
        }
    }
    END { dump_memo() }' "$@"
```

When run on the data file shown in the question, the original output from the unrevised script was:

```
gene.100079.0.0.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   86.7
gene.100080.0.3.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   99.9
gene.100080.0.0.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   99.9
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t2   transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   76.7
```

The main difference between this and what was requested is the sort order.  If you need the data in sorted order, pipe the output of the script through `sort`.

With the revised script (with the `/^chr/` rule) is:

```
gene.100079.0.0.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   86.7
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t1   transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   74.9
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t2   transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   76.7
gene.100080.0.3.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   99.9
gene.100080.0.0.p1  transcript:OIS96097 82.2    169 30  0   1   169 4   172 1.3e-75 283.1   99.9
```

Again, if you want the data in some specific order, apply a `sort` to the output.

Comment: I am sorry,, I did a mistake in the rules because  IDs starting with `chr` get excluded from the comparison and they end up straight in the output. I updated my question.

Comment: I've updated my answer — and provided the updated output.  If you want the `gene.100080` output before the `chr11` lines, then you'd have to do a little more work — call `dump_memo()` in the `chr` rule before printing the line and zapping the `memo_*` data (setting `memo_num` to zero, and setting `memo_key` and `memo_val` to empty strings — all in the function, probably, and optionally but preferably making some other adjustments too).OTOH, if you're going to sort the output, the order of printing doesn't really matter.  Please be careful in future — get the question details right first time.

Comment: Thank you, I will. I don't mind the output order because I can use `| sort -k 1`

Comment: YW.  Note that `sort -k 1` is functionally the same as `sort`.